# dnn WebApi - DnnAuthorize methods not working?

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke, asp.net-web-api

I created the following simple ping method in a dnn service framework using the web api.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Ping()
{
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Pong!");
}
```

Now this works fine calling from a browser. If then try changing to this

```
[DnnAuthorize]
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Ping()
{
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Pong!");
}
```

I get a popup username and password request in the browser. Every time I enter the details, the login box just reappears as if its wrong.

I also tried `[DnnAuthorize(StaticRoles="Administrators")]` but that did the same.

So I then downloaded the Dnn Dash Service source and loaded the desktop app project. Replaced the following line

```
string url = DnnRequest.GetUrl(credentials.HttpAlias, "DnnDash_SimpleDashboard", "Dash", "PingHost", false);
```

with

```
string url = DnnRequest.GetUrl(credentials.HttpAlias, "RegisterService", "Register", "Ping", false);
```

so that it would work with the above method in my service. Running the project results in a 500 error.

Any ideas why I done wrong?

EDIT 1

I uploaded the dnn dash service to my site and then ran the desktop app. Still the same issue, so I know at least its not my service.

EDIT 2

I cleared my dnn log and then ran the desktop app a few times. Went back to the log and opened the newly created file. Found a few of the following entries which matches me running the desktop app.

```
[Thread:99][FATAL] DotNetNuke.Web.Common.Internal.DotNetNukeHttpApplication - System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Password Retrieval is not enabled
at System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
at System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

EDIT 3

OK the error in EDIT 2 seems to be caused when you set the dnn site up using hashed passwords. I switched over to Encrypted passwords and now I get a response from the service saying "not authorised". Just need to figure out why an Admin logging is not authorised.

NOTE: When switching from hashed passwords to Encrypted, this will only affect new users. For existing users you need to run an SQL script to update the password format and you need to reset the passwords.

Comment: So does edit 2 mean you've fixed the issue? If not, have a look at [this DNN issue](https://dnntracker.atlassian.net/browse/DNN-27209).

Comment: Try inspecting the request header and the response from the server with Fiddler and see if you get down to the issue.

Comment: @Gaz83, if your edits describe your solution, feel free to answer your own question. It will be a helpful reference for other users.

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie no I just put it there so people can see the steps I have taken which may help them.

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie Once it's solved I will create an answer. I still have authorization issues even though I am using admin login details.

Comment: @Gaz83 did you ever get to the bottom of this?

Comment: I'm trying to access Web API methods from another application and CONSTANTLY get 401 not authorized and have yet to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but I encountered a similar issue and was able to fix it properly.
To authorize administrators on a request you can't simply pass a string. Reason is there's a good chance per instance of dnn the admin role has a different name such as "Administrators", "Administrator" (no 's') ect. To get around this issue write it like so:

```
[HttpDelete, DnnModuleAuthorize(AccessLevel = SecurityAccessLevel.Admin)]
```

If you need to access this role name elsewhere in your code you can use this snippet.

```
private string GetAdminRoleName()
    {
        return PortalSettings.AdministratorRoleName;
    }
```

Hope that helps someone. Sorry this is a late response.